# Autoscroll multipage figures, avoid jumps in overlays

Tags: beamer, graphics, floats, pdf, overlays

I have a multipage pdf image and I want to put it into a beamer slide with an `itemize` environment in overlay. I want the page of the pdf image to automatically scroll each time an item appears.

In other words, I'm wondering whether there exists an option like `<+->` for `\includegraphics` (the documentation of graphicx doesn't say anything about that).

```
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.25\textheight}
        \only<1>{\includegraphics[page=1]{img/multipage}}
        \only<2>{\includegraphics[page=2]{img/multipage}}
        \only<3>{\includegraphics[page=3]{img/multipage}}
        \only<4>{\includegraphics[page=4]{img/multipage}}
    \end{overlayarea}
    \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.55\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> first item, appears on page 2
        \item<3-> second item, appears on page 3
        \item<4-> third item, appears on page 4
        \item<4-> fourth item, appears on page 4
    \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

Another (very annoying) issue is that the figure "walks" around the frame at each page. I've tried using `overlayarea` but it does not seem to solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed such an option: `\includegraphics<+>[page=1]{example-image}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
        \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.25\textheight}
            \includegraphics<+>[page=1]{example-image}
            \includegraphics<+>[page=1]{example-image-a}
            \includegraphics<+>[page=1]{example-image-b}
            \includegraphics<+>[page=1]{example-image-c}
        \end{overlayarea}
        \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.55\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<2-> first item, appears on page 2
            \item<3-> second item, appears on page 3
            \item<4-> third item, appears on page 4
            \item<4-> fourth item, appears on page 4
        \end{itemize}
            \end{column}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I needed to add the width to the `\includegraphics` optional argument so that the figure would be the right size: `[page=1, width=\linewidth]`.